# Wrapping an Integer

Tags: java, wrapper, word-wrap

I need to make a constructor that accepts an integer to be wrapped. I currently have:

```
public class IntegerRateable implements Rateable {

    private Integer object;

    public IntegerRateable(Integer object) {
        this.object = new Integer(object);
    }
```

I am unsure what is wrong with my code. I was under the impression that this should allow it to be wrapped.

Comment: What do you mean by "allow it to be wrapped"? And why do you believe your code to be "wrong"?

Comment: Maybe you are confused with the auto-boxing of an `int` to an `Integer`?

Comment: `this.object = object;`

Comment: Ah, `new Integer(anInteger)`, that reminds me of the time I took a trip by car, but then I realized I needed to bring my car with me, so I put my car in the trunk of my car, and started off...

Comment: Yeah I just learned about it so I don't have too much knowledge about it

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is, your `IntegerRateable` class to contain an Integer as member variable, try this:

```
public class IntegerRateable implements Rateable {

    private Integer object;

    public IntegerRateable (int number) {
        this.object = number;
    }
```

Then, just instantiate `IntegerRateable` object as:

```
IntegerRateable integerRateable = new IntegerRateable(5);
```

Comment: Don't really need the constructor, you can just rely on autoboxing.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks for pointing out, true what you mentioned. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may first want to check your braces, you're missing a closing brace `}`.

If that's not the problem, I'am assuming that the problem is in this line 
    `this.object = new Integer(object);` . There is nothing wrong with this, it's just that it using the Integer constructor has been deprecated which you can find out more about here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#Integer-int-

So the preferred way of doing it would be to do `this.object = new Integer.valueOf(object);`

EDIT: Although, I don't see a point in doing this since you can just do `this.object = object;`

Comment: Why would you do that if you can just do `this.object = object`?